# Making pointy part of share count bubble with only CSS

Tags: html, facebook, css

I recently came across a [nice trick](http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2013/feb/04/richard-iii-dna-bones-king) on the Guardian's website. They've created this nifty fake Facebook share button.

[image]

The interesting bit is how they make the pointy part of the share count bubble. It's all done with CSS and two empty elements in the .facebook-share-count span which makes the bubble. Here's the HTML:

```
<span class="facebook-share">
    <a class="facebook-share-btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=180444840287&amp;link=http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2013/feb/04/richard-iii-dna-bones-king&amp;display=popup&amp;redirect_uri=http://static-serve.appspot.com/static/facebook-share/callback.html&amp;show_error=false" data-href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2013/feb/04/richard-iii-dna-bones-king" data-link-name="Facebook Share">
        <span class="facebook-share-icon"></span>
        <span class="facebook-share-label">Share</span>
    </a><span class="facebook-share-count"><i></i><u></u>197</span>
</span>
```

and this is the CSS. I can't figure out exactly how the  and the  are creating this pointy bit though. In my inspector they both have a computed width 0 and height 1px. Can anyone tell me how they're doing it?

```
.facebook-share-count {
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cdd5e5;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    position: relative;
    height: 14px;
}

.facebook-share-count i,
.facebook-share-count u {
    border: solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #D7D7D7;
    top: 4px;
    left: -5px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    border-width: 4px 5px 4px 0;
}

.facebook-share-count i {
    left: -3px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-right-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:before` pseudo selector in CSS to insert an a block that looks like an arrow.  The actual arrow shape consists of a border trick in CSS.

You can read more about this technique here:
http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/

Comment: Um thanks but I don't see a :before anywhere in the CSS - here's an example http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2013/feb/04/richard-iii-dna-bones-king.

Comment: Right.  They're actually including additional markup in the `.facebook-share-count` div.  They have `<i></i><u></u>` which are styled to together to form the arrow.  You don't have to include additional markup like they did to achieve these results.

Comment: Ah I get it now, thanks Axel, YuiBlog explains it quite clearly. Basically the 5px right grey border on these tiny elements makes the pointy shape (because rectangular borders intersect at a 45 degree angle), and they position the <i> with its white border above the <u> and offset it 2px to reveal the grey below.

Comment: Yup, exactly ;)  I was quite surprised when I found that trick used awhile ago.  It's nice that the limits of CSS doesn't end with squares.

Answer (score 2):

As Axel said, its using the :before pseudo selector, and also the :after, along with borders, margins and positioning properties.
If you're looking for a good resource that will help you build the arrow with a border like the one in your example: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Cheers maceyj2, I can only tick one answer but gave yours an upvote.